# Add Authorization rules to website without using IIS manager?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, authorization, windows-server-2008

We created a Web Site in our IIS that points to a folder with several simple HTML pages. The `application pool` is set to `asp.net v4.0`.

Only certain users can view these html pages, but everyone that logs on to the company's intranet can view them. I want to implement `authorization rules`, but the icon to add them is not displayed in IIS manager, even though `Management Services` is installed according to this [MSDN link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/management/authorization/authorizationrules/scope/add).

Is it possible to add these authorization rules without doing it through the `IIS Manager`? I know it wan be done by adding several keys to `web.config`, but what happens if web.config doesn't exist? This website doesn't have anything related to `asp.net`.

The server is running `Windows Server 2008` and `IIS 7`.

Wanted to add that I created a web.config for this particular folder that is supposed to block everyone, but nothing changed:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="*"/> // deny everyone else
    </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I believe that even website consists of static html pages, you can still add web.config at website root and then configure Windows Authentication. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication/

Comment: I had added web.config, but nothing changed. On the other hand, The web.config is being read because if it's not well-formed, everything from that site will show `500 - Internal server error.`.

Comment: Is your application pool pipeline mode `Classis` or `Integrated`?

Comment: It's `Integrated`.

Comment: The tag `system.web` is for ASP.NET pages. You need to use IIS's authorization, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/understanding-iis-url-authorization

Comment: Change `<system.web>` to `<system.webServer>` in your web.config and see if it works

Comment: The page isn't displayed, but it's with message `500 - Internal server error.`. I think there's something wrong with `web.config`.